# Many Independent linear regression or other Alternatives?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

Suppose I would like to investigate how multiple variables $[ x_1,\ldots,x_k]$ contribute to another variable $[ y ]$, I had intended to use a simple linear regression.

However, to see the contributions against a thrid variable [ Age ], any idea if it would be methodologically-wise to compute the regression analysis independently across Age and plot the $\beta$ values aginst Age ? (no need to worry about the sample size)

Else, would it be advised to group Age into Age Cohorts, and perform probably a Linear Mixed Model analysis instead ?

Suppose that I would like to achieve in somthing conceptually similar to the following graph:

[image: Illustration]

Comment: can you explain in detail what's your aim? what area you modelling exactly?

Comment: Interaction terms allow the selected variables to have their own effect of age, so for example males and females have their own slopes for age, implying that aging has a different effect for each. If you suspect that this effect is not linear and maybe something like what you have plotted you could try adding splines or some such.

Comment: @utobi -- I'm trying to predict how some psychological variables differs across Ages, usually it would be nice to simply do a linear regression for a particular age group, however, I am currently trying to see specific trend and thus am wondering whats the best way to deal with it. Thankss.

Comment: @user2974951 -- Thanks for your reply but Sorry I don't quite get it, do you mean adding interaction terms, let's say $ x_n*Age$ in the regression for interpretation purpose? upon demonstrating their interaction, for example, what shall I do if I would like to get an estimate on the $ x_1$ relative to other $x_n$ at a specific Age ?

Comment: @user2974951 -- alternatively, do you mean a LMM model with sth like: `lme(y ~ x1 + x2 + Age + x1*Age + x2*Age, random= ~1|gender)` ?